# Angularjs $resource not binding data with $scope in controller function

Tags: angularjs, binding, resources, scope

```
//my controller using $resource factory variable ownerSrvc
Owner.factory('OwnerSrvc', function($resource){
    return $resource('/owner/:id', {

            query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
            create: { method: 'POST' },
            show: { method: 'GET', isArray:true},
            update: { method: 'PUT', params: {id: '@id'} },
            delete: { method: 'DELETE', params: {id: '@id'} }
        }
    )
});

Owner.controller('ownerCtrl', function($scope, OwnerSrvc, $location){
    OwnerSrvc.query({id:'531784367883254406700e99'},function(data) {
        //  console.log(data[0]);        retrievig data of Mr. Ali
        $scope.owner = data[0];        binding works here at controller level;
    });

    //User defined function at Congtroller level

    $scope.editUser=function(ids){  //when i called this function later with id
        OwnerSrvc.query( //params{id:ids},    //my service giving me result fine
            function(data) {
                console.log(data[0]);                 //result showing in console OK  i.e. Mr. Zain
                $scope.owner = data;   // but data not binding with $scope.owner

            });

        console.log($scope.owner)  // here after Query called, $scope.owner showing old result i.e Mr. Ali instead of Mr. Zain
        $location.path('/owner');
     };
});
```

**My question is why the data is not binding at function level inside the controller. And how to bind new data with `$scope.owner`?**

Comment: Please correct the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't assign the same property inside the function.

On the ctrl your code is : 
    $scope.owner = data[0];

Inside the function edituser : 
    $scope.owner = data;

Moreover inside the function edituser you commented 
    //params{id:ids},

If you don't want to use param you should write at least {},